# Netsuite integration API

Tags: node.js

We are developing a fintech software and would interested to integrate our software with NetSuite. Is the any way to integrate with them without buying actual NetSuite license? Do they provide any open API for public to use and test?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your goal is that you want your fintech software to be integrated to a NetSuite account.

NetSuite uses the Software as a Service (SaaS) model. Customers who wish to use it needs to pay a subscription fee. [Know more about NetSuite here and how it works](https://www.netsuite.com/portal/resource/articles/erp/what-is-netsuite.shtml#:%7E:text=NetSuite%20uses%20the%20software%20as,and%20deploying%20patches%20and%20upgrades).

With your goal in mind, you need to figure out which NetSuite account will you be integrating to. I want to help you with some steps, in case you want to pursue working with NetSuite integrations:

1. Talk to a potential customer to let them give you access to a NetSuite Development Account
2. Establish the contexts of the integration, i.e. *Will you be sending or receiving data from NetSuite? or Will you be sending and receiving data to/from NetSuite?*
3. NetSuite SuiteCloud provides a comprehensive list of solutions depending on the integration context, i.e. SuiteTalk proves to be the easiest way to integrate with NetSuite because it's very straightforward and doesn't need much to get started. [Check out all the available platform integration features here.](https://www.netsuite.com/portal/platform/developer/suitetalk.shtml#target3)

I hope I was able to help you get started with enough information.